# Modify plain text response before outputting it to the client on Nginx

Tags: nginx, webserver

I'm setting up the [secure_link_module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_secure_link_module.html) on Nginx to protect direct access to `.m3u8` files, I was able to successfully configure it using an encrypted md5 and expires as query parameters, e.g:

```
example.com/video/sample.m3u8?md5=XXX&expires=YYY
```

that is working great for m3u8 files, but the problem is that inside `.m3u8` files that are several `.ts` files, and in order for it to work, it also must be accessed with the query strings (`sample.ts?md5=XXX&expires=YYY`).

example of m3u8's content:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:4
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:2
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:2.000000,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:155476@0
output0.ts // add query string
#EXTINF:2.000000,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:305124@155476
output0.ts // add query string
#EXTINF:2.000000,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:295912@460600
output0.ts // add query string
#EXTINF:2.000000,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:229548@0
output1.ts // add query string
```

I tried to use the `ngx_http_sub_module`, but unfortunately, it didn't work, code:

```
sub_filter_once off;
sub_filter ".ts" ".ts?md5=$arg_md5&expires=$arg_expires";
```

is there a way of searching and replacing line by line of the response only with Nginx? or is it possible to execute some script, like bash or even node.js, to replace the content of the file and output it on runtime without actually changing the file.